# How to apply boot splash via xfce4-session?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, plymouth

I am using `Xubuntu` and I am trying to customize boot splash. There are several options under the Splash tab in `xfce4-session` (Balou, Simple, Mice) but I don't know how to apply them. Official [docs](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/preferences) lacks of information. Just clicking on them didn't work...

Does anyone knows how to apply them?